# Cannot find what exports CDPATH

Tags: bash, linux-mint

I made the mistake of putting CDPATH into my `.profile` file just to see if it would slightly boost my productivity but found that sometimes it would `cd` to directories that I didn't want it to (I would need to precede them with `./` to make sure it went to the current directory rather than one defined in the environment variable that shared the same name).

I removed it from the `.profile` file but it still gets exported every time I launch the terminal and for the life of me I can't find what (bash) script does it.

I would search`/etc` and my home directory for any file the name of which resembles `profile` or `bash` and `xargs grep` those files to look if there were something along the lines of `export CDPATH` but to no avail.

Is this stored in a configuration file that `cd` uses? Has anyone come across a similar problem?

Needless to say I did put `export CDPATH=''` in my `.profile`, but I need to source it first for the statement to take effect.

My bash version is 4.2.24, my OS is Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.profile` will be read when you **log in** not when you start a new shell. This includes when you log in to a graphical display manager, which I assume you are doing ("every time I *launch* the terminal"). If you're in a graphical interface, log completely out of that and back in to get a fresh environment.

EDIT: For future reference, I recommend putting stuff like that in a `.bashrc` file instead of `.profile`. The `.bashrc` is read every time a shell is started. [This page](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) does a good job of explaining the difference in more detail.

Comment: Yes, it was indeed the issue, I was using a virtual environment whose state I was saving and once logged in, the variable was there until I would restart it. I had assumed that the CDPATH would be unset for all terminals if I did it in one but it wasn't the case. I'll keep it in mind :)